# How to get access to Firebase Storage anonymously?

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I'm trying to get access to files in Firebase Storage without any credentials.

As documentation says these rules allow access for everyone.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm getting error:

```
Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.list access to bucket_name. [401]
Errors [
    Message[Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.list access to bucket_name.] Location[Authorization - header] Reason[required] Domain[global]
]
```

I tried both with Cloud Storage SDK for .NET and direct web requests to JSON API

```
var storage = StorageClient.CreateUnauthenticated();
var objects = await storage.ListObjectsAsync("bucket_name", "prefix").ToList();
```

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket_name/o?key=api_key' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

What did I miss or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Firebase security rules only apply to access from the Firebase client SDKs for Android, iOS, web, and Unity.  They won't apply when using one of the server SDKs or other cloud-provided mechanisms.  Perhaps you want to look into Cloud Storage ACLs to specify permissions.  https://medium.com/google-developers/firebase-google-cloud-whats-different-with-cloud-storage-a33fad7c2b80

Comment: Sounds like an answer Doug! :)